BartForConditionalGeneration: Adding additional layers of embedding
In this file:
https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/main/src/transformers/models/bart/modeling_bart.py

I think-

Inside the BartEncoder, on this line, I have to add other embeddings

Could anyone tell me - are there any other places I need to modify to add additional layers of embedding?
Could anyone tell me - are there any other places I need to modify to add additional layers of embedding (e.g., 2 other embedding with positional embedding)?

What are you trying to achieve? Are you only using the encoder or also the decoder? The line you have mentioned is the forward pass.

@cronoik task is classification (using encoder + decoder)
